# How to break line in #3 of \pdfcomment

Tags: pdfcomment

My question is as the title suggests.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Underline,color=blue!1,timezone=+08’00’]
           {Department}
           {name\\ Tel：123456}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hyperref defines `\textCR` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Underline,color=blue!1,timezone=+08’00’]
           {Department}
           {name\textCR Tel：123456}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JohnKormylo you mean the stamp at the top? That's what adobe shows in such a comment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo you need a pdfviewer which can show comments.

Comment: Never mind.  I wasn't putting the mouse over the text.